# Is there a way to write a module that contains a function that returns a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example, given this short dataset:

```
data = [ ['6623', '2009-11-15'],
        ['6623', '2010-04-04'],
        ['6623', '2011-03-06'],
        ['6623', '2011-03-19'],
        ['6623', '2011-09-07'],
        ['6624', '2011-09-11'],
        ['6624', '2012-01-04'],
        ['6624', '2012-04-25'],
        ['6624', '2012-08-03'],
        ['6625', '2012-07-15'],
        ['6622', '2010-10-05'] ]
```

I need to write down a python code to get a list of lists with max and min value of the first column + its associated day. Following the previous dataset:

```
[ ['6622', '2010-10-05'],
 ['6625', '2012-07-15'] ]
```

I started with this code, then I stopped my self because I do not have any idea how to combine min/max value with its associated day

```
def getDateRange['a', 'b', 'c']:
    minval = min[data]
    maxval= max[data]
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! your function definition doesn't make sense... are you following a tutorial or class?

Comment: Thank you! I am at the very beginning. I know it doesn't make sense, I just wanted to show what I'm able to do at this moment. Feel free to suggest whatever you think I need to solve my problem.

Comment: when you define a function (`def`) you should specify its inputs with parenthesis like `def getDateRange(a, b, c):` and really only should input variables and not strings.

Comment: The answer to your question is of course yes, but I don't think you're ready for it... you're code isn't python, so you need to start with the basics. There are plenty of resources online for tutorials and [so] is not intended to fill that role.

Comment: @DavidSilveiro Help fixing the OPs code should be posted as an answer, not edited into the question. This is doubly so after answers are already posted, as we don't want to invalidate someone's answer.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Thanks buddy, remembered for the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python defining and calling a function both use parentheses rather than square brackets to enclose parameters. Since sequences are ordered according to the order of the first item, or the second item, if the first items are the same, etc., you can simply call `max` and `min` with the list of lists to obtain the desired output:

```
def getDateRange(data):
    return [min(data), max(data)]
```

so that given your sample input, `getDateRange(data)` returns:

```
[['6622', '2010-10-05'], ['6625', '2012-07-15']]
```

Comment: This is unlikely to work on real data, as `'9'` is larger than `'10'` when compared as strings.